# sstp vpn on MacOS Sonoma - could not complete write of frame, could not forward packet to pppd

Tags: network, homebrew, vpn

I'm a little green in this type of things, but I was trying to connect vpn through home-brew to my University vpn, because they state it's the only option on Mac. I use this command:

```
sudo /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sstp-client@1.0.13/1.0.13/sbin/sstpc\
  --log-stderr  --cert-warn --user “username” --password “password” \
  vpnaddres usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault\
  defaultroute refuse-eap noccp
```

And I get an error

```
Dec 16 09:52:45 sstpc[40319]: Could not complete write of frame
Dec 16 09:52:45 sstpc[40319]: Could not forward packet to pppd
Dec 16 09:52:47 sstpc[40319]: Connection was aborted, Reason was not known
**Error: Connection was aborted, Reason was not known, (-1)
```

I tried updating homebrew, reinstalling the sstp-client from homebrew, restarting my computer. I created a local tap for sstp 1.0.13 as I know 1.0.14 has serious problem. What else can I try? or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`brew install sstp-client`

Note:
The process of executing each command is quite long. You must wait until each command is completed in full.

Create a script file using the nano text editor
`nano sstp.sh`

Paste the following content into this file:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sstp-client/1.0.19/sbin/sstpc --cert-warn --tls-ext --user "user" --password "password" xxx.domen.com usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault noccp refuse-eap refuse-pap refuse-mschap defaultroute
```

Make the sstp.sh file executable by changing its resolution to 755
`chmod 755 sstp.sh`

Connect to the SSTP server by running the script
`./sstp.sh`

To check whether the client has connected to the sstp server or not, you need to open another terminal and type the following commands in it:

`ifconfig -a`

Option for command output upon successful connection:

`ppp0: flags=8051 mtu 1500 inet xx.xx.xx.xx –> xx.xx.xx.xx netmask 0xff000000`